# スワイプで上下左右にページ移動するアプリはどう作るのでしょう？

Tags: monaca

Monacaを使い始めたばかりの初心者です。

スワイプ操作で上下左右にページ移動するアプリを作りたいのですが、どうすればいいでしょうか？

「Onsen UI最小限のテンプレート」のボタン操作をスワイプに置き換えるような感じです。

アドバイスいただけたら幸いです。

Answer (score 1):

自己解決しました。後続の人のために方法の骨子を書いておきます。

1）index.htmlのbodyタグ内

```
<ons-navigator var="myNavigator" page="page001.html"></ons-navigator>
```

２）page001.html

```
<ons-gesture-detector>
    <ons-page >
        <div class="container"></div>
    </ons-page>
</ons-gesture-detector>
```

３）index.htmlの

```
ons.ready(function() {

    /* 前ページにスワイプ */
    $(document).on('swiperight', '.container', function(event) { });

    /* 次ページにスワイプ */
    $(document).on('swipeleft', '.container', function(event) {
      myNavigator.pushPage( "page002.html" ); 
    }); 
}
```